# How to change line spacing for text in UILabel swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked at solutions on stack and they have not helped me.  The following is my attempt to change the line spacing for the text in my UILabel.  Please can someone advise.  I see no effect on my line spacing.

```
 let myText = abstractText.text!
 let myParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 myParagraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5

 let myNsAttrStringObject = NSAttributedString.init(string: myText, attributes: ["paragraphStyle":myParagraphStyle])
 abstractText.attributedText = myNsAttrStringObject
```

Comment: Take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872266/1556386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attribute key is not correct in this way, you can use objective-c key **NSParagraphStyleAttributeName** or swift 4 key **NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle**:

```
let myNsAttrStringObject = NSAttributedString.init(string: myText, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: myParagraphStyle])
```

Comment: could you share with me the link to the NSAttributedStringKey?  This is the link that i have and i cannot find the key you suggested: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey

Comment: Your link is correct you can set it with paragraphStyle key in this way: `NSAttributeStringKey.paragraphStyle`

Comment: I get 'unresolved identifier- NSAttributeStringKey' when i do it the way you just suggested 'NSAttributeStringKey.paragraphStyle'

Comment: Are you using Swift 4? I have updated my answer because NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle is available from Swift 4.